# How to get password input field ID of gmail wiht selenium Webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The new JS enabled page of http://mail.google.com is making trouble to get ID of password input field. However, I've navigated from email ID page with its ID - `identifierID` .

How can I get the ID of password field?

Comment: can you paste the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the updated code:

**Code:**

```
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.c‌​om"); 
    WebElement elementid = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")); 
    elementid.sendKeys(""); 
    WebElement elementnxt = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")); 
    elementnxt.click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")));
    WebElement elementpwd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']"));
    elementpwd.sendKeys("123");
```

I have validated it on my end. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @Monika for your suggestion, but in I'm still not getting expected outcome. I used ` WebElement elementpwd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("div[@id='password']//input"));
         elementpwd.sendKeys("123");`

Comment: You have made mistake in your path. Please try this: WebElement elementpwd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='password']//input")); 
        elementpwd.sendKeys("123");

Comment: I did the same as you suggested. But my testing getting stucked on the next page (after entering email id and clicking next button) of password field. Can I share the code which can help you to review?

Comment: You have missed "//" in your XPath. Your lines of code is: driver.findElement(By.xpath("div[@id='password']//input")), this doesn't have "//" before div. For relative xpaths you have to use "//".

Comment: It was mistake in comment. Otherwise my code line is as - `WebElement elementpwd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='password']//input"));`

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) {       
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\vicky\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\AutoBot\\chromedriver.exe"); WebDriverdriver=newChromeDriver();driver.manage().window().maximize();driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
WebElement elementid = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
elementid.sendKeys("vishvajit.bakrola@utu.ac.in");
WebElement elementnxt = driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext"));
elementnxt.click();WebElementelementpwd=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='password']//input"));elementpwd.sendKeys("123"); }`

Comment: Please copy it and take it to your editor.. Due to character limitation in comment I managed it and not sounds well... :)

Comment: I have already shared. Check the answer. I gave updated my answer with the latest code

Answer (score 3):

Instead if Id use name attribute to get access of the field.

```
document.getElementsByName("password")[0];
```

It will give you password input element.

```
<input type="password" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="current-password" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Enter your password" name="password" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="">
```

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, I even have used name as well as name attribute. But, not getting outcome as expected.

Comment: I have used this -`gmail.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys("xyz");`

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination input element and the div having Inner text

`<div jsname="YRMmle" class="AxOyFc snByac" aria-hidden="true">Enter your password</div>` .

Also on clicking the correct element, the parent element changes which makes you to find the element again and send the value.

You can use CssSelector or Xpath to attain this easily. But you Google will definitely be changing this so often.

Comment: Then how can one(without using password input field) make test case of gmail page.

Comment: We have to find the password input field element , click the password input field, and then find the element again and send the data to field. @Vicky

Comment: Have tried to access the same using xpath, name, ID, etc. But still not able to derive the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the value of the field using JavaScript

as

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("var elements = document.getElementsByName('password');elements[0].setAttribute('value', '123');");