# Making a program in Python that logs you in email

Tags: python, email, webdriver, restful-authentication

So i'm total beginner and i came to a problem. So this is part of my program:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('https://accounts.google.com/signin'
         '/v2/sl/pwd?service=mail&passive=tru'
         'e&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmai'
         'l.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmp'
         'l=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&f'
         'lowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSe'
         'ssion&cid=0&navigationDirection=forward'))

username = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierNext')
nextButton.click()

password = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME('whsOnd zHQkBf')))

password.send_keys(passwordStr)
```

First part where it puts my username works nicely, also the part where it clicks on next button works.

But i can't make it work for password. In username you have ID tag and you can easily find element by ID, but password doesn't have this. This is password HTML:

`<input type="password" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="current-password" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Vnesite geslo" name="password" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="">`

I tried calling it as class name or link text but it's just not working.
Thanks for all answers

Comment: Have you tried `EC.presence_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME('whsOnd')))`

Comment: Why not search for input[type=password] since only one will be present

Comment: Still getting  "!TypeError: 'str' object is not callable", no matter what

Answer (score 0):

The link below is for selenium, but it should work the same with Chrome: find_element_by_tag_name ("input") or find_element_by_name ("password") should both work
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: No matter what i try it keeps giving me error:
!TypeError: 'str' object is not callable".
It worked with username though.
Any ideas?

Comment: click first? see https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18415/selenium-sendkeys-not-inserting-value-into-textbox/20736

Comment: "data-initial-value" is what changes when I type in the field. It likely can be set directly !? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172977/how-can-i-change-an-attribute-value-in-the-dom-using-selenium-and-python

Comment: There's no need to click first. It is already clicked, same as with username.

Comment: On inspection, the text part is input.whsOnd.zHQkBf (the class parts). Maybe you need to specify these ? Did you see the js comment? it may not work both ways, as filling the form changes the argument, but filling the argument doesn't see to fill the form...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738306/how-to-get-password-input-field-id-of-gmail-wiht-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help B.Go, but it didn't really help me what you posted.

I decided to rewrite code, with the same logic as i did first part

```
time.sleep(1)
password1 = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
password1.send_keys(passwordStr)
```

It magically works now. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is the solution I found. You have to let the program login to your email, so you have to disable the safety settings. 
It`s a more direct way using SMTP lib.

```
import smtplib

server=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)          #when you use gmail
server.starttls()
server.user="your@email"
server.password="yourPassword"
server.login(server.user, server.password)
msg="Hello world"
server.sendmail("your@email", ["receiver@email", "also more"], msg)
server.quit()
```

MFG